# Angular takes Array as object and does not display the values

Tags: php, html, angular, typescript, angular5

// Updated along the discussion

I try to get JSON objects(Tasks) via http request and parse them into my own class to display them on my HTML page(Task Overwiew).

This is what I get:

[image]

This is the json array my php returns:

```
    {"result":[{"id":"3","znumber":"vor21423"},{"id":"2","znumber":"vor213"}]}
```

Here's my last try from the turtorial on angular.io. I've tested many answers but most of them relate to `.json()` which is no longer part of the HTML client.

```
export class ApiComponent {
 private apiUrl = 'http://localhost:81/work/get.php';

 results: Steve[];

 constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
 }

 ngOnInit() {
   this.getSteves();
 }

 getSteves() {
   this.http.get<ItemsResponse>(this.apiUrl)
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.results = data.result
          .map(steve => new Steve(steve.id, steve.zNumber));
            console.log(this.results);
            console.log(data);
      });
  }
}
```

The Interface

```
import { Steve } from './Steve';
export interface ItemsResponse {
  results: Steve[];
}
```

HTML

```
<div>
  <div *ngFor="let steve of results">
    <p> - {{steve.id}}</p>
    <p> - {{steve.zNumber}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

The Steve Class

```
export class Steve {
  public id = 0;
  public zNumber = '';

  constructor(id: number, zNumber: string) {
    this.id = id;
    this.zNumber = zNumber;
  }
}
```

The API

```
<?php 
require_once('db.php');

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM jobs ORDER BY id DESC';
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $data = array();
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $data[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode(array('result' => $data));
} else {
    echo 0;
}
?>
```

Comment: try inspecting the `data` object while debugging I believe you should use `result` not `results`.

Comment: I thougt that results is just an identifier for the json array. // 'steves' by now

Comment: The `results` is a variable and as such, can be named anyway you want. The conventions is to use singular, so `result`. It looks like `data` object coming from the server has no `steves` property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you are not receiving an array, but an Object, so you need to get the array from the object `result`. Secondly, if you want to make the objects in the array instances of `Steve`, you need to explicitly tell Angular so.

You `ItemsResponse` actually looks like this (notice the `result` instead of `results`):

```
import { Steve } from './Steve';

export interface ItemsResponse {
  result: Steve[];
}
```

The request should show that you are getting response of type `ItemsResponse`.

```
 getSteves() {
   this.http.get<ItemsResponse>(this.apiUrl)
     .subscribe(data => {
       // your array is in 'result' object of your response
       this.results = data.result
         // create instances of your class
         .map(steve => new Steve(steve.id, steve.znumber))
     });
  }
```

Comment: Okay thank you! The output now shows the id's but not the znumber string. Any idea why the znumber is undefined? // updated the screenshot.

Comment: Because `znumber` is coming from backend but you expect `zNumber`. Replace: ` .map(steve => new Steve(steve.id, steve.zNumber))`
with:
` .map(steve => new Steve(steve.id, steve.znumber))`

Comment: i changed znumber to zNumber in my database. It Works. Thank you guys so much for the help :)

Answer (score 2):

You are using Angular version 4 at least. In version 4 the Angular team decided to implicitly parse JSON results, so you wouldn't have to write `JSON.parse(json.result)` with each Ajax request.

In your example you replaced the value returned by server: `result` with `steves` and then you try to access it: `data['steves']` but in the screenshot you can see that the values have already been extracted by Angular implicit JSON parsing and you are dealing with an array of objects.

So `data['steves']`, `data['result']` etc. will always be undefined, cause the Angular HttpClient service, which replaced Http service in version 4 is already parsing JSON before it returns the data.

Just replace:
`this.results = data['steves'];`
with
`this.results = data;`
and everything will work.

Comment: You no longer have access to data['result'], since HttpClient parses it for you, removing result and assigning its value to data and then returning it.
So the `data` that's returned is already an array you return from the server. There is no `result`, `results`, 'steves' and whatever else you had as the first property of your JSON when returning it from the backend. HttpClient already parsed it for you.

Comment: I can' just asign data to this.results . I get this error -> error TS2322: Type 'ItemsResponse' is not assignable to type 'Steve[]'.
  Property 'includes' is missing in type 'ItemsResponse'. data.results throws no error but gives me the same output as schown in the screenshots // updated the question to my current code

Comment: That's because of this line:
`this.http.get<ItemsResponse>(this.apiUrl)`
In essence you just told TS compiler that your return value is `ItemsResponse`which has `results` property and then you try to assign it to `this.results` of `Steve[]` type. So the interfaces are incompatible. Use `this.http.get<Steve[]>(this.apiUrl)` cause this is what you get back from the server - a list of Steves.

Comment: `Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'.` means that you try to iterate over object properties instead of array in `*ngFor`
So if you have `<div *ngFor="let steve of results">` in your template, `results` should be an array, not an object.

Comment: Thank you so far!! I dont get why angular think its an object. It is declared as Array, is it?

Comment: I think you are trying to do something funny inside subscribe. Maybe paste your code here.
If you get `Steve[]` from the server and your `this.results` field is also of type `Steve[]`, you just need to assign one to the other, no need to use wrapper `Steve` class.
So just do: `this.results = data;` in a callback passed to subscribe.

Comment: Well, you are not doing anything funny in the subscibe, your code looks alright. You should not be seeing `Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'` error anymore. Do you still have some issues?

Comment: Yes .. even after dev server restart

Comment: Can you double check that `data` in subscribe is actually an array. If it is and you pass it to `*ngFor` in a template you should not be seeing the `Cannot find a differ...` error. Unless there is something else going on, in that case paste in the error message you are still getting.

Comment: okay thats strange. look at the updated screenshot. i made 4 logs

Comment: Something has changed and now you receive the object with result property, @AJT_82 has a good explanation for that.